# All buttons are clicked at the same time instead of the specific one clicked

Tags: reactjs

I am much confused as I don't know what I am doing wrong. Each time I clicked on the plus sign, all the other div elements display instead of the specific one I click on. I tried to use id argument in my show and hide functions, it is complaining of **too many re-rendering** . I have been on this for the past 12 hours. I need your help to solving this mystery. All I want to do is to click on the plus sign to display only the content and minus sign to hide it.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'


function Home() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    const [showing, setShowing] = useState(false)
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState("")
    async function getData() 
        {
           let response = await fetch('https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students');
           let data = await response.json();
            return data;
        }
        
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
        .then(
           data => {
               setUserData(data.students ) }
        )
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          })
    }, [])
    const handleFilterChange = e => {
        setSearch(e.target.value)
     }
    function DataSearch(rows) {
        const columns = rows[0] && Object.keys(rows[0]);
        return rows.filter((row) =>
        columns.some((column) => row[column].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        );
    }
    const  searchPosts = DataSearch(userData);

    const show = (id, e) => {
           setShowing(true); 
    }

    const hide = (id, e) => {
       setShowing(false);
    }
    return (
        <>
              <div>
                         <input value={search} onChange={handleFilterChange} placeholder={"Search by name"} /> 
                     </div>
            {
                
                searchPosts.map((student) => (
                    <div key={student.id} className="holder">
                      <div className="images">
                          <img src={student.pic} alt="avatar" width="130" height="130" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="data-container">
                      <span className="name">{student.firstName.toUpperCase()} {student.lastName.toUpperCase()}</span>
                      <span>Email: {student.email}</span>
                      <span></span>
                      <span>Company: {student.company}</span>
                      <span>Skill: {student.skill}</span>
                      <span>City: {student.city}</span>
                     
                     { showing ? 
                      <button id={student.id} onClick={hide}>-</button> 
                      : <button id={student.id} onClick={show}>+</button>
                      }
                      <div data-id={student.id}>
                          { (showing )
                          ? student.grades.map((grade, index) => (
                        
                          <span id={index} key={index}>Test {index}: {grade}%</span>
                          
                      )) : <span>
                        
                      </span>
                    
                    }
                      </div>
                      
                      </div>
                      
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change,

```
const [showing, setShowing] = useState(false)
```

to:

```
const [showing, setShowing] = useState({});
```

Here change the useState from boolean to object.. Reason for this is we will store the ids as keys and a boolean value indicating if the grade should be shown or not.

And remove Show and hide function and have a common toggle function like,

```
  const toggleGrades = (id) => {
    setShowing((previousState) => ({
      ...previousState,
      [id]: !previousState[id]
    }));
  };
```

You are using `setShowing(true)` in show function and `setShowing(false)` in hide function which is the reason for opening all and closing all at any click.. Because you have never mentioned which exact grade should be shown so you need to make use of id here..

And buttons click handler will be like,

```
{showing[student.id] ? (
    <button id={student.id} onClick={() => toggleGrades(student.id)}>
      -
    </button>
    ) : (
    <button id={student.id} onClick={() => toggleGrades(student.id)}>
      +
    </button>
)}
```

So pass student id `() => toggleGrades(student.id)` in both show and hide button an make the button gets toggled.

Display the grades like,

```
<div data-id={student.id}>
  {showing[student.id] ? (
    student.grades.map((grade, index) => (
      <span id={index} key={index}>
        Test {index}: {grade}%
      </span>
     ))
    ) : (
      <span></span>
    )}
 </div>
```

Here if `showing[student.id]` will display only the grades of clicked item.

And that is why id plays a major role in such case.

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit React Functional Component (forked)]

Comment: Hi ! Nice solution, I def recommend it. But I was wondering, wouldn't it be easier to split the content mapped into a separate component ?
Doing so, each components would have is own state, so you don't have to bother with the ids

Comment: @ChandelierAxel, Yes we can do in that way as well but in order to be straight forward for OP question, I have made a simpler solution like this..

Comment: Please can you explain? I have been struggling with this for the past 12 hours. More also, I need to a mentor to learn more

Comment: Thank you so much, please is possible to find the sum of the grades

Comment: @Payne, Here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-q9pgn  .. For visibility I have added more ```<br />``` tags but in your real app if you don't want that then you can remove it..

Comment: Thank you so much... I have got it working. I appreciate it

Comment: @Payne, It is because the data type you receive is string for that number so you have to convert it to number and add with the previous one.. That is why we have gave it like ```return (sum = +sum + +item);``` here ```+sum``` and ```+item``` will make the string to number..

Comment: I sent you and email via hotmail. I want to learn from beginning.